# Customizing chromium source code to create a custom browser for android

Tags: android, chromium

I want to create a new web-browser for android, but this browser is not like ordinary web browsers. This is only useful to open local (html, css and js) files and to do some local tasks like disk reading, playing music, etc. It won't open any web URLs.

So i thought to customize chromium source code. How to customize it according to my requirement ?

I downloaded chromium source code and built using ubuntu linux. But it has many projects and directories. I tried to understand the source code architecture with help of [this link](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/getting-around-the-chrome-source-code). But i am getting confusion, because some files mentioned in that link are not available in source code.

if anybody know about chromium porting and customization please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you dont usa a WebKit to this purpose. Many web browsers using this web engine also your chromium. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/package-summary.html